# How to make DB request in Laravel 6 for a difficult Request?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My request is:

```
SELECT DATE(`main_date`) `date`, SUM(`total`) `sum_value` FROM 
SELECT db1.main_date, db2.total FROM database_1 db1 INNER JOIN database_2 db2 ON db1.id = db2.main_id 
WHERE (user_id LIKE 111 AND DATE(`main_date`) LIKE '2020-01-01')) AS totals 
GROUP BY DATE(`main_date`);
```

It works perfect in SQL, however in Laravel I could make this part:

```
$db->select(DB::raw("DATE(`main_date`) `date`, SUM(`total`) `sum_value`")
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(`main_date`)")
->get();
```

But where to place main the most important part:

```
FROM 
    SELECT db1.main_date, db2.total FROM database_1 db1 INNER JOIN database_2 db2 ON db1.id = db2.main_id 
    WHERE (user_id LIKE 111 AND DATE(`main_date`) LIKE '2020-01-01')) AS totals
```

I really don't have any idea about it. :(
Thank you for your support!

Comment: @Strawberry There is an error: "Every derived table must have its own alias" if this AS something didn't place after the FROM ___BIG REQUEST____ part.

Comment: 'It works perfect in SQL' I disagree: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT db1.main_date, db2.total FROM database_1 db1 INNER JOIN database_2 db2 ON' at line 2`

Comment: Anytime you are using `DB` in Laravel, you should ask yourself if you are doing things right. Relations between models and query builder convenience methods should cover almost all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use DB facade with your query, like this:

```
DB::select('SELECT DATE(`main_date`) `date`, SUM(`total`) `sum_value` FROM 
SELECT db1.main_date, db2.total FROM database_1 db1 INNER JOIN database_2 db2 ON db1.id = db2.main_id 
WHERE (user_id LIKE 111 AND DATE(`main_date`) LIKE '2020-01-01')) AS totals 
GROUP BY DATE(`main_date`)')
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT db1.main_date, db2.total FROM database_1 db1 INNER JOIN database_2 db2 ON' at line 2` Please test code before posting

Comment: there is a ( missing before the second select direct after the FROM